# Finite difference based regularization matrix

Tags: regularization, tikhonov-regularization

I've just started reading about Tikhonov Regularization. Would someone please help with a simple numerical example of a case where regularization matrix of the form of a second order finite difference (tridiagonal matrix with 1,-2 and 1 at appropriate places) can be useful.

I'm guessing curve fitting might be a simple use case. But need a bit of help to understand exact usage.

Comment: My answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234280/is-tikhonov-regularization-the-same-as-ridge-regression/250842#250842) is one example. Curve fitting would also be a reasonable example. In that context a curvature-based penalty would be a way to essentially get a smoothing spline (2D case [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit)).