# Constrained (regularized/damped) solution of system of linear equations in Matlab

Tags: least-squares, matlab, regularization, constrained-regression

I have an overdetermined system of linear equations `A*X=B`. Where `X` is a column matrix with N unknowns. The least square solution of this system can be obtained in Matlab as `X = mldivide(A,B)`. However, I want a solution `X`, such that the sum of second order differences between different elements in `X` is minimum. That is, to find a solution `X`, such that the following error term is minimum:

$E = ||\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{B}||^2+\sum_{j=2}^{N-1}[X_{j-1}-2*X_j+X_{j+1}]^2$

Comment: @DeltaIV Thanks. I have edited the question to include full error term. However I didn't get your point about 'distance among points'.

Comment: Forget it, it was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting hints from the comments and lot of literature survey, I have solved the above problem by myself. The above said error can be minimized by means of **Tikhonov regularization** of second order. Error term in general Tikhonov regularization is given as

$$E = {\|\textbf{A}\textbf{X}-\textbf{B}\|^2_2+\lambda\|LX\|^2_2}$$

Where $\lambda$ is damping factor and $L$ is regularization matrix. $L$ can have many forms. If $L$ is replaced by an identity matrix $I$, it is known as **ridge regresion**. Another common practice is to replace $L$ by finite order difference matrix. For our concerned error term, $L$ will replaced by second order difference matrix, i.e.
 $$L=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   -1&  2 &   -1 &     &     &  0\\
     & -1 &    2 &  -1 &     &   \\
     &    &  ... & ... & ... &   \\
     &    &      &  -1 &  2  & -1\\ 
  \end{array} } \right]$$

The solution by Tikhonov regularization can be then obtained by solving the following linear system:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} A \\ \lambda L\end{array}\right]X = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} B \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$
You will have to decide on value of $\lambda$ (see **L Curve** in references).

References:

1. Noschese, Silvia, and Lothar Reichel. "Inverse problems for regularization matrices." Numerical Algorithms (2012): 1-14.
2. Calvetti, Daniela, Lothar Reichel, and Abdallah Shuibi. "Invertible smoothing preconditioners for linear discrete ill-posed problems." Applied numerical mathematics 54.2 (2005): 135-149.
3. Hansen, Per Christian. The L-curve and its use in the numerical treatment of inverse problems. IMM, Department of Mathematical Modelling, Technical Universityof Denmark, 1999.

Comment: FYI this would typically be called [regularized](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/250722/the-origin-of-the-term-regularization) regression, rather than constrained. (Although Tikhonov can be expressed as an inequality constraint.)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Thanks. I have edited the question title to fit better into the context.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but in case it wasn't clear: this is exactly the method I was talking about in my answer, and that is used in the paper I referenced.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing sounds exactly like what is sometimes called a "graph ridge"/"graphridge" regression, which is like a ridge regression (if that's something you're familiar with) but with a penalty not on the (squared) regression coefficients themselves, but on the (squared) differences between coefficients that are connected in an assumed graph structure. In your case, you'd let $X_j$ and $X_k$ be connected in this graph if $|k-j|=1$.

This type of regression is convenient because like the "regular" ridge regression, it has a closed-form solution. For more info see e.g. [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/19c6/a93d714f5871b1a66cf2c71a71d611348c24.pdf) which makes use of this method (esp. equation 14).