# Clarifying Dual Representation

Tags: machine-learning, ridge-regression

$$ w =  (X^T X + \lambda I_n)^{-1} X^T y \rightarrow \sum^m_{i=1} \alpha_i x_i \\ 
\alpha = (\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_m)^T \rightarrow (XX^T + \lambda I_m)^{-1} y $$

From what I understand, the above demonstrates the conversion from *primal* to *dual* form. However, I am at a loss as to the definition and meaning of each of these forms and how the transformation takes place. I would appreciate help in understanding:

1. What is the definition of *primal* and *dual* representation?
2. How does one convert between *primal* and *dual* form?
3. What benefit does the conversion offer?

Comment: This help? http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234281/99274

Comment: This sounds like a linear programming problem.