# Detrending a time series

Tags: time-series, trend

I have time series data from 1947-1971 for prices and quantity indices.  In the original paper from 1975 which I obtained the data the authors did not detrend the data.  Here is how I detrended the data:

1. I applied the Hodrick Prescott filter to each of the variables via Eviews
2. I obtained the residuals values from the Hodrick Prescott and examined them.
3. It was good because of no trend so I took the residuals and replaced them for each of the variables. Then I proceeded to the estimation of the model.

Would this be correct approach to detrend the data?

Answer (score 2):

The [HP filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodrick%E2%80%93Prescott_filter) was not conceived as a simple detrending method, it proposes a way to estimate the cyclical component of a time series, leaving you with the potential long-run component.

Many scholars argue against its use, as for example James  Hamilton in his article "[Why You Should Never Use the Hodrick-Prescott Filter](http://econbrowser.com/archives/2016/08/why-you-should-never-use-the-hodrick-prescott-filter)" ([shorter presentation](http://econbrowser.com/archives/2016/08/why-you-should-never-use-the-hodrick-prescott-filter)). You should be careful whenever you use it.

That being said, if you simply want to detrend the data, you could estimate:

$$
y_t=\beta t + \varepsilon_t
$$

and then use the residuals $\varepsilon$ as your detrended series, just like you did with the HP estimation.

Comment: Interesting, I had never heard of the HP filter before! It is essentially Tikhonov regression with a curvature penalty (e.g. as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234280/is-tikhonov-regularization-the-same-as-ridge-regression/250842#250842)). If you make the penalty coefficient $\lambda$ large, the HP result should converge to the linear fit, I would think (?) The issue in Hamilton seems to be "not appropriate for a random walk" (?), which could also apply to a purely linear trend. (Or is Hamilton only arguing against "certain values of $\lambda$?)