# Non-Ridge Kernelized Regression?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, ridge-regression, kernel-trick

Every presentation that I have seen for kernelized regression focuses on finding
$$\underset{f \in \mathcal{H}_k}{\min} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-f(\mathbf{x}_i))^2+\lambda \|f\|^2_{\mathcal{H}_k}.$$
Here, $\mathcal{H}_k$ is a [Reproducing kernel Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space) (RKHS).

I was wondering

- Why the focus on ridge regression? Can we use other penalties here, or is there something about the ridge penalty that is natural in this setting?
- Can we do un-penalized kernelized regression? Why is this not usually presented prior to kernel ridge regression?

Comment: RKHS has a structure that lends itself to Tikhonov regularization. There is a lack of motive for doing otherwise.

Comment: @Carl Could you elaborate on the first point?
Also after some thought, I reasoned that no regularization wouldn't be good since there may be many $f$ in the RKHS that minimize the loss. The regularization term gives us a unique solution. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Perhaps your understanding is correct, however, I cannot entirely put myself in your thought process. OK try this, compare the Wikipedia link I put into your question with my Q/A on [Tikhonov/ridge regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/234280/99274). Maybe that will allow you to verify your train of thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question!

**Alternative Norms Exist (kind of):** Though we call it "Kernel Ridge", let's take a second to note that the norm we're using is the RKHS norm (whereas regular "ridge regression" penalizes the $\ell_2$ norm of the parameter vector). One could consider a different function space norm to be penalized instead, like an $L_p$ norm. Alternatively, we could directly penalize the kernel coefficients, as in this [article about kernel lasso](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v2/wang07a/wang07a.pdf). But yeah, what's so nice about the RKHS penalty is that its solution is available in closed form (from the Bayesian perspective, it is a conjugate prior to the normal likelihood). GPs wouldn't be nearly as popular if you needed to solve a nonlinear optimization program to use them. (but you often do anyways if you have enough kernel hyperparameters to estimate...)

**Other Approaches than Penalties Exist (kind of):** The reason we usually use regularization in kernel regression is because we have, in effect, an infinite dimensional parameter space, with one "column" associated with each possible input location: $k(\mathbf{x},.)$. Without regularization, there are not only infinitely many solutions which interpolate our data (which is possible in underdetermined, finite-dimensional regression), but indeed most of those solutions are made of infinitely many kernel functions $\hat{f}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i k(\mathbf{x}_i,.)$. So we want some way of simplifying things. But it doesn't have to be a penalty per se. Usually we solve:

$$ \min_{f\in\mathcal{H}_k} \sum_{i=1}^N (f(\mathbf{x}_i)-y_i)^2+\lambda||f||_{\mathcal{H}_k} $$

which has solution given by $\alpha = (\mathbf{K}+\lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ then $\hat{f}=\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i k(\mathbf{x}_i,.)$.

But instead of solving a penalized problem, we could instead solve this constrained one:

$$ \min_{f\in\mathcal{H}_k} ||f||_{\mathcal{H}_k}$$
$$\textrm{Such that:}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N (f(\mathbf{x}_i)-y_i)^2 = 0 $$

Which has solution given by $\alpha = (\mathbf{K})^{\dagger}\mathbf{y}$, where $\mathbf{A}^\dagger$ gives the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of $\mathbf{A}$. [I should mention I have the noiseless case in mind here, where $y_i$ is observed exactly as $f(\mathbf{x}_i)$].

Now the reason I put "kind of" above is that this is clearly what the limit of our penalty method gives us as $\lambda\to 0$, so while not a penalty method, it is a limit of them. There may be other, truly different ways of sieving it down to a finite dimensional approximation space that are useful in applications, but I haven't personally run into them.